# Extending type conversion to pairs/tuples of convertable types

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I've got to deal with a bunch of 2D point types: `pair<double>`, `pair<float>`, `pair<int>`, and I'd like to allow implicit conversions between points whenever there exists a conversion of their coordinates. Something like this:

```
template< class From, class To > 
inline operator pair< To, To > ( pair< From, From > that )
{
    return make_pair( static_cast< To >( that.first ), 
                    static_cast< To >( that.second ) );
}
```

Unfortunately, `g++` objects:

convert.cpp:5: error: ‘operator std::pair(std::pair)’ must be a nonstatic member function

Is it possible to do the above w/out defining wrapper classes for the `pair`s?

Comment: No. You may declare your own pairs: double_point2d, float_point2d, int_point2d and provide proper conversions.  (You may consider a template, here)

Comment: An conversion function doesn't take arguments. You can make it a regular (possibly static) member function.

Comment: An alternative to wrapper is to derive from `pair`, but there is lots of problems doing that too. I think your operator wouldn't work implicitly even as a member function, because the template parameters in the return type are not deducible from function arguments (or by implicit you mean some blind `static_cast<T>` where `T = pair<X,X>`?). And, finally, just my opinion: implicit casts usually decrease readability, so it's better to keep that as a function (again, unless if you mean by `static_cast`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make implicit conversion to an unknown type; and again, conversion operator must be a non-static member function which will still require you to wrap it a class; and write a converting constructor from an unknown type (aka templated constructor).

Why don't you want to make it a free function:

```
template<typename To, typename From>
std::pair<To, To> convert(const std::pair<From, From>& p){
    return std::make_pair( static_cast< To >( p.first ), 
                static_cast< To >( p.second ) );
}
```

And then call it like:

```
std::pair<float, float> mp{3.424, 59.35};
auto p2 = convert<double>(mp);
```

That's just about as clear as it can be. See it [Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f0293e2103fb453)

**EDIT** 
*(As per OP's comment)*:

You could do a quick Type for that sort of thing:

```
template<typename T>
class Point{
public:
    T x = T{};
    T y = T{};

    template<typename Y>
    Point(Point<Y> p) : 
        x(static_cast<T>(p.x)),
        y(static_cast<T>(p.y))
    { }

    Point(T x_val, T y_val) : x(x_val), y(y_val)
    { }

    Point(Point&&) = default;
    Point(const Point&) = default;
    Point& operator = (Point&&) = default;
    Point& operator = (const Point&) = default;
};
```

Consider this function that uses a `double` as the type parameter to `Point`:

```
void print(Point<double> p){
    std::cout << "(" << p.x << ", " << p.y << ")\n";
}
```

The statements below will all work because of the Converting constructor.

```
int main() {
    Point<float> mp{4.535, 395.3};
    Point<int> ip = mp;
    print(mp);
    print(ip);
    return 0;
}
```

See it [Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ba0f23ce8ebe8dc)

Comment: Because I don't want to contaminate the rest of the code with `convert` statements. If function `foo` takes parameter `pair<double,double>` and variable `bar` is defined as `pair<float,float>` I want the call look like `foo(bar)`, not like `foo(convert<double>(bar))`.

Comment: @Michael, Your only way out is to wrap it in a class. See my updated answer. How about [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ba0f23ce8ebe8dc)